How should I correctly display the new section?
My problem is that when I try to create a new section or any new content after the homepage, it doesn't appear on a new page but still displays on the homepage itself. I have uploaded the project to codepen as an example, where I created an h1 section titled "new part" to illustrate my issue. I also figured out specifically what is causing this.In this section(what can you find in the right content part), the CSS includes the position: absolute property.
<div class="col-lg-4 p-0">
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="vid-overlay"></div>
      <video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="hands.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>

.col-lg-4.p-0 
    {
      height: 100vh;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }

If I remove this, the content displays correctly, but the video's position becomes incorrect. This causes overlapping issues in desktop view and also doesn't work properly in mobile view, affecting several functionalities.Is there any alternative to achieve the same result as using position: absolute?

Please add the relevant code - and only the relevant code - to your question, remove everything that's not required to reproduce the problem you describe.

If you want to have a 2 column layout with the video on the right and all other content on the left, then it's quite easy.
First put all the content inside a div, the navbar the h1 everything. The the video should be in its own separate div. After that, you should create a div to contain both the content div and the video div. Finally apply flex to the container div to get your desired layout.


.overall-container {
  display: flex;
 }
<div class="overall-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <nav>...</nav>
    <h1>...</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video>...</video>
  </div>
</div>



If you want to improve you HTML and CSS skills consider following me on medium where I post blogs to help you become a better developer.
